# custom error page in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to show up the error page using customerror on `web.config`

But watever the error may be, even in web.config i specified some version wrong also it need to show the error page,

How can I do this. I tried but url redirects to

```
"http://localhost:1966/Error.html?aspxerrorpath=Error.html"
```

CustomError Tag:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.html" />
```

And shows up another error page from mvc, not mines.

Comment: Error Redirect is only working in my IIS not in local VS dev server.

Answer (score 7):

In ASP.NET MVC error handling is normally specified using the [HandleError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) attribute. By default, it uses a View named 'Error' to display the custom error page. If you just want to customize this View, you can edit Views/Shared/Error.aspx.

If you want a different View in particular cases, you can explicitly supply the View property.

Here's an example of a Controller action with a custom Error View:

```
[HandleError(View = "CustomError")]
public ViewResult Foo() 
{
    // ...
}
```

For global error handling in ASP.NET MVC, see [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/12/01/GlobalErrorHandlingInASPNETMVC.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution as Mark described above HandleError attrib.

Another solution to catch errors is to have a baseclass the all you controller class derives from. And inside the baseclass ovveride OnException method to show a user friendly error view that you have in for example "~/Shared/Error.aspx"

You also need to have `<customErrors mode="On" >` defined in your root web.config for this solution to work.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public BaseController()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Log the error that occurred.
        log.Fatal("Generic Error occured",filterContext.Exception);

        // Output a nice error page
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            View("Error").ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
        }
    }

}
```

Above solution catches most of the possible "yellow screen of death errors" that occurs.

To handle other errors like 404 i use folowing mapRoute last in global.asax RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)

```
// Show a 404 error page for anything else.
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Error",
                "{*url}",
                new { controller = "Shared", action = "Error" }
            );
```