# Pass exception to custom error page in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

How can I pass exceptions to my custom error page and present them the same way you can on the standard error page you get when you first create a new application? The code below works on the standard error page but not on my custom. Any ideas?

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}

<h1 class="error">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="error">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

@if (Model != null)
{
    @Model.Exception.Message
    @Model.Exception.InnerException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define customError configuration in web.config here you can give path for error page.

```
<customErrors mode="On">
   <error code="404" path="404.html" />
</customErrors>
```

for more info see these links

http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

[How to make custom error pages work in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905164/how-to-make-custom-error-pages-work-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

[custom error page in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033261/custom-error-page-in-mvc)

Comment: I've already added these but I want my custom error pages to treat 500 exceptions as well. The question is how.